# Running numbers in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL-statement like this:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE deleted = 0;
```

How can i create a result set with a running number in the first row? So the result would look like this:

```
1 Name_1
2 Name_3
3 Name_12
4 Name_15
...
```

Comment: It's DBMS dependent -- what do you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
FROM    users
WHERE   deleted = 0
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  @r := @r + 1 AS rn
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars, users
WHERE   deleted = 0
ORDER BY
        name
```

In `PostgreSQL 8.3`:

```
SELECT  num, (arr[num]).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  generate_series(1, array_upper(arr, 1)) AS num, arr
        FROM    (
                SELECT  ARRAY
                        (
                        SELECT  users
                        FROM    users
                        ORDER BY
                                name
                        ) AS arr
                ) q
        ) q2
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL server 2005 you can use row_number() over(order by yourColumn), like this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY myColumn) FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your DBMS -- in Oracle, you can use rownum in the select.  There is no standard SQL way, but most DBMS's support some way to do it.

Here's mysql:

http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/

Here's SQL Server

http://samsudeenb.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-generate-rownum-in-sql-server.html